# More details for StorageException

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

How to retrieve from StorageException a blob Id?
StorageException contains only ServiceRequestID, http related details, start/end request time and exception message and stacktrace.

Comment: What kind of details do you want?

Comment: requested operation - upload, download, delete etc.

Comment: Isn't the blob id, and the operation already known to you? Since you are handling the exception?